# Add filter on attributes having some special Characters in their attribute name

Tags: geotools, filter

We have a Feature layer having multiple attributes. One attribute having attribute name is `BSC/RNC` . we create some filter on that attribute :-

```
String strQuery = "BSC/RNC >= 10";
org.opengis.filter.Filter flt = CQL.toFilter(strQuery);
```

but it gives the result with all records having attribute `BSC/RNC` as `NAN` values.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
String strQuery = "\"BSC/RNC\" >= 10";
```